# Send documents on upload to other app

Tags: workflow, web-services, document, web

I am wondering if it is possible to to send documents when they are uploaded to sharepoint to another app.

I am new to sharepoint and have tried digging around the SPFx library and the CSOM API but nothing really jumps out at me so far.

Comment: Where you want to send it exactly, which "app"?

Comment: I'm trying to send it to an R shiny app that was made.